# PF states table give preoccupant results

Tags: security, firewall, openbsd, pf

I freshly install openBSD on a VPS. It is my first time. I did nothing but check the firewall setup, say pf. I ran pfctl -sa and it show

```
all tcp IP0:22 <- IP1:rnd ESTABLISHED:ESTABLISHED
all tcp IP0:22 <- IP2:rnd ESTABLISHED:ESTABLISHED
all tcp IP0:22 <- IP3:rnd FIN_WAIT_2:FIN_WAIT_2
all tcp IP0:22 <- IP4:rnd TIME_WAIT:TIME_WAIT
```

with IP0 my server IP, IP1 my local IP, but IP2, IP3, IP4, are completely unknown IP to me. There is some repetitions of the last two lines with diferent port number (rnd). I tried to understand the information in the table with few success, I am completely a newby in web traffic and so on...

Should I be preoccupated with that second line which suggest a third party is connected to my server?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line doesn't mean that someone is *logged in*, it merely indicates that someone made a connection to the port.  After connecting, the client will then try to authenticate itself, using the established connection.

If you are still suspicious you can test this yourself: log in via SSH on one terminal, open another terminal and run `ssh` and wait at the password prompt. Now run `pfctl -sa` on the other terminal and you'll see your IP come up twice: one for the logged in terminal and another for the 'waiting' connection.

`/var/log/authlog` should show you the list of all successful and failed login attempts.

Comment: Many thanks. It helps a lot. I can confirmed '/var/log/authlog' has now 0 information since 2 days, even if I connect. And tcpdump show me communication with a fix ip including several type of flags S,R,P, with various from my ip to the unknown ip. How can I investigate a bit more?

Comment: `sshd` defaults to `LogLevel INFO` and `SyslogFacility AUTH` (see `man 5 sshd_config` if you need more details), and these defaults should log all successful logins and unsuccessful attemps on `/var/log/authlog`. If you haven't changed these directives you should have something on your authlog. Do the rotated logs in `/var/log/authlog.*.gz` have anything?

Comment: Thanks Zé. I checked yet Logvel and SysLogFacility. It was ok. And I check all logfiles. It appears that my authlog stops completely! I connected and nothing was written on!  I decided to change my ssh port, install few pf rules, and changed my various privates keys. Just in case. Very strange because logs was on. I don't know what could blocked it. Moreover, I saw what appears to be real communications with P, . , F etc flags on 22 port.

Comment: It is normal to see "real communications" between hosts, they _do_ need to communicate in order to establish a connection (try to login using `ssh -vvv` and see all that goes on before the server requests a password and the client is logged in). That doesn't mean someone has logged in. It is normal for internet-exposed hosts to be hammered with SSH login attempts. Changing ports doesn't help much (see [this blog post by Peter Hansteen](https://bsdly.blogspot.com/2013/02/theres-no-protection-in-high-ports.html)).